# Heroku: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, ssh-keys

I'm learning Ruby at the Odin Project and I'm doing all of my installations.

I am all the way to deploying a Heroku Test app, but when I try to push the app it gives me the following error:

```
 !    UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE: unable to verify the first certificate
```

Not sure what to do here.

Comment: I'm running Rails on Windows 10 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can figure out, it seems more like a certificate issue.

Try removing all the old installations of Heroku gem by :

1. Try running `heroku update` first and see if the issue is resolved. 
   ELSE follow 2, and 3.
2. `gem uninstall heroku` ( uninstall the toolbelt. )
3. Install the Heroku toolbelt again.